# Django mongonaut: 'You do not have permissions to access this content.'

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have got example simple Django + Mongoengine app from here https://github.com/sneawo/django_mongo_test
This is simple blog app that store posts in Mongodb.
Now i want admin interface, for this i found django-mongonaut http://django-mongonaut.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

I passed all install instructions, but still when trying to access `localhost:8000/mongonaut/` i see *You do not have permissions to access this content.* What is the worst  - there is no any login form.

This is my mongoadmin.py

```
# myapp/mongoadmin.py   http://django-mongonaut.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html

# Import the MongoAdmin base class
from mongonaut.sites import MongoAdmin

# Import your custom models
from blog.models import Post, Tag

# Instantiate the MongoAdmin class
# Then attach the mongoadmin to your model
Post.mongoadmin = MongoAdmin()
Tag.mongoadmin = MongoAdmin()
```

I am new to django, this is my last chance to work with Django + Mongodb, i took several days going through multiple tutorials i found in net - tried django-nonrel with mongodb-engine, and other options.

I am really frustrated, because i cannot find full working tutorials, some of them works, but with unexpected errors. 
Also i tried Quokka http://quokkaproject.org/but it is alpha and some pages don't work too...

Comment: This is on a mongodb that has auth on?  Are you sure the correct credentials got to the mongodb instance if needed?

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins answered below

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: i need to login to Django using standard admin interface and sqlite3.db, and after that session engine starts recognize mongonaut admin (this is bad workflow i think).
Also i am using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regme/0.2.5